# (PythonCrashCourse) Alien Invasion Highscore

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The highscore of my project so far is working, however, after my ship gets hit, the current score doesn't reset itself. For example, if I get 4000 points and my ship gets hit, during the next round, the highscore and current score is displayed as 4000 points.

game_stats.py:

```
    class GameStats():
         def __init__(self, ai_settings):
              self.ai_settings = ai_settings
              self.reset_stats()
              self.game_active = False
              self.high_score = 0

         def reset_stats(self):
              self.ships_left = self.ai_settings.ship_limit
              self.score = 0
```

scoreboard.py:

```
    def show_score(self):
         self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
         self.screen.blit(self.high_score_image, self.high_score_rect)
    def prep_high_score(self):
         high_score = int(round(self.stats.high_score, -1))
         high_score_str = "{:,}".format(high_score)
         self.high_score_image = self.font.render(high_score_str, True, self.text_color, 
              self.ai_settings.bg_color)
         self.high_score_rect = self.high_score_image.get_rect()
         self.high_score_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
         self.high_score_rect.top = self.score_rect.top
```

game_functions.py:

```
    def check_high_score(stats, sb):
         if stats.score > stats.high_score:
             stats.high_score = stats.score
             sb.prep_high_score()
    def check_play_button(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, 
    aliens, bullets, mouse_x, mouse_y):
         button_clicked = play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)
         if button_clicked and not stats.game_active:
              ai_settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()
              pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
              stats.reset_stats()
              stats.game_active = True
              aliens.empty()
              bullets.empty()
              create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
              ship.center_ship()
```

Comment: Other than inside of `GameStats.__init__`, where are you calling `reset_stats`?

Comment: I also called it in game_functions, which I just edited in the module above

Comment: Show us as much as possible, this is not enough to be a reproductible example

Answer (score 0):

This is a project from 'Python Crash Course' book, right? If so, your code is fine, score should reset only when your ship gets hit 3 times (ships_limit), not when it is hit the first or second time.